# Best Practice - NSError domains and codes for your own project/app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nserror

There is a [previous SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779034/nserror-domains-custom-domains-conventions-and-best-practices) regarding setting up error domains for your own frameworks, but what is the best practice regarding setting up error domains and custom error codes *for your own project/app*?

For example, supposing you're working on a Core Data-intensive app with lots of validations, should you just stick with the "off the shelf" Core Data error codes (such as `NSManagedObjectValidationError` from `CoreDataErrors.h`) or should you create your own `MyAppErrors.h` and define errors with more specificity (i.e., `MyAppValidationErrorInvalidCombinationOfLimbs`?

Creating a custom error domain and set of error codes could significantly disambiguate your code, but is it too much overhead to maintain and does one have to worry about error code numbering conflicts?  Or are there other concerns here?

Answer (score 154, accepted):

I personally use a reverse-DNS style domain.  For example:

```
NSError * myInternalError = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"com.davedelong.myproject" code:42 userInfo:someUserInfo];
```

The third part of the domain (`@"myproject"`) is just used to differentiate the errors from this project (`"My Project"`) from errors in another project (`"My Other Project"` => `com.davedelong.myotherproject`).

It's a simple way to ensure that I'm not going to conflict with anyone else's error domains (if I'm using 3rd party code), unless that developer is purposefully trying to mess with *just* me (which I believe would be highly unlikely...).

As for code numbering conflicts, don't worry about that.  Just as long as codes are unique *within a domain*, you should be OK.

As for translating errors, that's up to you.  Whatever you do, make sure you document it well.  *Personally*, I usually just pass on framework-generated errors as they came to me, since I'm never quite sure that I'll handle all the codes and translate all of the userInfo into something more specific to my project.  The frameworks could change and add more codes, or change the meaning of existing codes, etc.  It also helps me more specifically identify where the error came from.  For example, if my [StackKit](http://stackkit.com) framework generates an error in the `com.stackkit` domain, I know that it's a framework problem.  However, if it generates an error in the `NSURLErrorDomain`, then I know that it specifically came from the URL loading mechanism.

What you *could* do is capture the framework generated error and wrap it in a new error object that has your domain and a generic code, something like `kFrameworkErrorCodeUnknown` or something, and then place the captured error in the `userInfo` under the `NSUnderlyingErrorKey`.  CoreData does this a lot (for example, if you try to `save:` an `NSManagedObjectContext`, but you have relationship integrity errors, you'll get a single error back, but the `NSUnderlyingErrorKey` will contain much more information, like specifically which relationships are wrong, etc).

Comment: Since apple also uses reverse DNS it seems appropriate for other to use this style as well.

Answer (score 39):

I don't have enough rep to comment, but for the accepted answer by Dave DeLong, it might be slightly better to use `[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]` instead of `@"com.myName.myProject"`. This way, if you change your name or project's name, it will be reflected accurately.

Comment: Good idea. If you're using Swift, you should use the unwrapped optional: `NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleIdentifier!` (if you know the bundle identifier is set, which I guess will be most likely)

Comment: Why would you want to reflect project name changes in the error domain?

Comment: @zrxq There is value in having different error domains for sure, but imagine you misspelled your project or you changed your name an wanted it reflected everywhere. Better have it dynamically set than hard coded.

Comment: @vare That much is clear, I don't really understand what practical benefits would that provide. My understanding is those identifiers just need to be unique in the context of the app, that's all. Okay, maybe you just want them to be more aesthetically pleasing, I get it!

Comment: Yeah, you bring up a good point. There are times when you want the domain to be unique, I would assume ... for example perhaps if you're create an SDK or (cocoa)Pod, you would want your error domain to reflect where it came from, not the project's name.

EDIT: I also (in my answer) wanted to point out that @"com.myName.myProject" is identical to the bundleIdentifier in this case, which people might not know.

Answer (score 5):

How to create a custom NSError:

First create a Dictionary of the error message

```
NSDictionary *userInfo = @{   
   NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: NSLocalizedString(@"Unknown Error - Please try again", nil),
   NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey: NSLocalizedString(@"Unknown Error - Please try again", nil),
   NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestionErrorKey: NSLocalizedString(@"Unknown Error - Please try again", nil)
                                               };
NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier] 
  code:-58 userInfo:userInfo];
```

Then assign the userInfo to the NSDictionary and your done.