# NSError from HTTP status code

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection

What's the best way to create an `NSError` object based on a standard HTTP status code (ideally one which includes some human-readable message in the `localizedDescription`)? Is there a standard method or should I just create my own error domain to use with `NSError`?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779034/nserror-domains-custom-domains-conventions-and-best-practices?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Foundation's objects for performing network requests will often return these `NSError`s for you. `NSURLConnection`, for example, will provide an `NSError` in the `completionHandler` of its `+sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` method.

If you'd like to roll your own you could create an instance of an `NSError`, set its error domain to be `NSURLErrorDomain`, set its `code` to be the HTTP status code you want, and set its `localizedDescription` to be the human readable string you need.

Comment: Seems to me adding my own error codes to a domain I don't control is a bad idea.

Comment: Yeah, you could also have your own error domain, that probably doesn't answer your question of having stock NSURLErrors

Comment: When the connection succeeds and the server responds with an error code, the `NSError?` passed to the `completionHandler` is `nil`.

Comment: I'd like it if this answer was right, but it seems to be wrong. The most obvious status codes I checked -- 404 and 500 -- don't return any `NSError` at all, just `nil`.

Comment: this is incorrect - NSError will only be created if the NETWORKING layer has failed. If networking succeeded, and server sent, say, 402 status, no NSError will be created. I am looking for such code to build a robust NSError representations for the plenty http status scenarios, for a long time now.